# $a!b!$ multiple of $a! + b!$ implies $3a\geq 2b + 2$

Tags: number-theory, inequality, contest-math, divisibility, factorial

A colleague asked me to show that if $a,b\in\mathbb{N}^*$ are such that $a!b!$  is a multiple of $a! + b!$, then $3a\geq 2b + 2$.

While I could verify this inequality numerically for many solutions $(a,b)$, I did not find anything relevant mathematically. I must say I have never faced such inequalities in arithmetic... 
The problem is symmetric in $a$ and $b$, and actually I could see that the solutions where all such that $3a\geq 2b + 2$ *and* $3b\geq 2a + 2$.

Here is a plot of the first solutions $(a,b)$ and the bounds:

[image]

The solutions can be generated with the *Mathematica* code:

```
Table[If[IntegerQ[a!*b!/(a! + b!)], {a, b}, 
 Unevaluated[Sequence[]]], {a, 1, 100}, {b, 2, 100}]
```

Comment: this is wrong for $a=b=1$

Comment: @Vasya But 1 is not a multiple of 2

Comment: $a=82$ is kinda curious. It works with $b=78$ and $b=80$, but doesn't work with $b=79$ or $b=81$. I think for $b\le a\le82$ this never happens. There are no gaps among the allowed values of $b\le a$.

Comment: Anyway, with $a\ge b$ the divisibility condition is equivalent to
$$1+a(a-1)(a-2)\cdots (b+1)\mid b!$$
This condition is very difficult to satisfy because no prime factor of $a(a-1)\cdots(b+1)$ will appear in the left. For example,
$$82\cdot81\cdot80\cdot79+1=11^2\cdot19^2\cdot31^2,$$ which is kinda miraculous.

Comment: Why $\frac{b}{a} \leq \frac{3}{2}$, it seems that $\frac{b}{a} \leq 1+\epsilon$ such that $\epsilon>0$ very small is sufficient, am i wrong ?

Comment: this is a continuation for the work of Jyrki Lahtonen $78,82,137,141,148,152,155,159,185,189,196,200,202,206,224,228,259,263,264,268,278,282$ are all the numbers that differ by $4$ , no numbers differ by $5$ for all $a,b \leq 600$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assume wlog. that  $b\ge a$. Then both $a!b!$ and $a!+b!$ are divisible by $a!$ and $a!+b!\mid a!b!$ implies $1+\frac{b!}{a!}\mid b!$. For $a<k\le b$, $1+\frac{b!}{a!}$ is coprime to $k$. We conclude that $1+\frac{b!}{a!}\mid a!$.

For $1\le k\le  b-a$, $k$ has a multiple $qk$ with $a<qk\le b$, hence is again coprime to $1+\frac{b!}{a!}$. We conclude $1+\frac{b!}{a!}\mid \frac{a!}{(b-a) !}$, in particular $$\tag1\frac{b!}{a!}< \frac{a!}{(b-a) !}.$$
By comparing the not cancelled factors in $(1)$ with $a$, we obtain
$$ a^{b-a}<a^{2a-b}$$
and hence (for $a>1$)
$$\tag2 2b<3a.$$

To improve this, observe that one of $b-a+1, b-a+2$ is not prime (or we are in the trivial case $b=a+1$), hence can be written as product of numbers $<b-a$ and is once again coprime to $1+\frac{b!}{a!}$. This allows us do divide off one more factor on the right of $(1)$, thus leading to $2b<3a-1$ and hence
$$ 2b+2\le 3a.$$

Comment: The fact that if $1\le k\le b-a$, then $k\mid \frac{b!}{a!}$ is true because there are $k$ possible different remainders when you divide an integer modulo $k$, so $k$ divides any product of $k$ consecutive integers, and $1\le k\le b-a$, so $k$ divides any product of $b-a$ consecutive integers. In particular, $k$ divides $(a+1)\cdots (a+(b-a))=\frac{b!}{a!}$. Also, $k$ divides (i.e. creates remainder $0$ after division) at least one of $a+1, \ldots, a+(b-a)$.

Comment: You wrote "can be written as product of numbers $<b-a$" but it should be $\le b-a$ because of cases like $2(b-a)=b-a+2$, $3(b-a)=b-a+2$, $2(b-a)=b-a+1$, $2((b-a)+1)=b-a+2$, where you should check case $2((b-a)+1)=b-a+2$, i.e., $b=a$ separately. But the proof still works. $k$ where $1\le k\le b-a$ divides any product of $k$, in particular $b-a$, consecutive integers, in particular $(a+1)\cdots (a+(b-a))=\frac{b!}{a!}$.

Answer (score 4):

This problem is $2015$ IMO Shortlist Number theory N$2$. [Two solutions can be found here on page $66$.](https://www.google.lt/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.imo-official.org/problems/IMO2015SL.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwirwfvj4a_WAhXCJJoKHXmPAooQFggfMAI&usg=AFQjCNESpvEBj_ToTv8K0F0zNXCNxwOUyw)

[Some solutions can be found, e.g., here on Art of Problem Solving.](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1268852p6622214)

Comment: May I ask how you found the links? Or maybe you had seen the problem before?

Comment: @anderstood I had seen the problem before.

Answer (score 1):

$a>b$ implies triviality so let's assume $b>a$. Let $b=a+m$.

We will prove by contradiction by assumes

$$2a+2m+2>3a\implies a < 2m+2 \implies a -m \leq m+1$$

Now

$${a!a!\over a!+a!(a+1)...(a+m)}={a!\over 1+(a+1)...(a+m)}=r$$

$$a!=r+(a+1)...(a+m)$$

Note that ${a\choose m}={a!\over m!(a-m)!}$ so $m!$  | $(a+1)...(a+m)$

(Note: it is the case that $m<a$ because otherwise $r < 1$ and cannot be an integer)

Also because $m!|a!$ we have $m!|r$ so $r >=m!$

Now

$${a!\over 1+(a+1)...(a+m)}=r >=m!$$

$$a! >=m!+m!(a+1)...(a+m)$$

$$(m+1)(m+2)...(a-1)a >=1+(a+1)...(a+m)$$

Note there are $a-m$ numbers on the left and $m$ number on the left.

(1) If $a -m <= m$ then contradiction is proven

(2) If $a-m = m + 1$ then $a = 2m+1$

$$(m+1)(m+2)...(2m)(2m+1) >=1+(2m+2)...(3m+1)$$

Note that we can prove

$${(m+1)(m+2)...(2m+1)\over(2m+2)(2m+3)...(3m)(3m+1)} < 1$$

hence contradiction.

The proof by induction for $m\geq4$:

Base case:

$${5\cdot6\cdot7\cdot8\cdot9\over10\cdot11\cdot12\cdot13} = 0.88 < 1$$

Induction step:

$${(m+2)...(2m+3)\over(2m+4)...(3m)(3m+4)} $$ $$= {(m+1)(m+2)...(2m+1)\over(2m+2)(2m+3)...(3m)(3m+1)}\cdot {(2m+2)^2(2m+3)^2\over(m+2)(3m+2)(3m+3)(3m+4)}<1\cdot1 < 1$$

Notice the polynomial is true because the first coefficient of $m^4$ is $16$ on top and $27$ in bottom. And plug in $m=4$ works so any $m\geq4$ works.

For cases $m\leq 3$ we know ${3a-2\over 2} < b \leq a+3 \implies 2a+6 > 3a-2 \implies a < 8$ so there is only a small finite number of cases to check.